# Formatting a Dictionary to a String with Variable Number of Values

Tags: python, dictionary

Given a dictionary

```
  x = {'b': {d}, 'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 'c': {'e', 'f'}, 'e': {d}}
```

I want a function that will print out:

```
  a -> ['b', 'c']
  b -> ['d']
  c -> ['e', 'f']
  d -> ['g']
  e -> ['d']
  f -> ['d', 'g']
```

I wrote this:

```
def graph_as_str(graph : {str:{str}}) -> str:
    graphString = ''
    for key in sorted(graph):
        graphString += '  {} -> ['.format(key)
        for value in sorted(graph[key]):
            graphString += '\'{}\', '.format(value)
        graphString = graphString[:-2]
        graphString += ']\n'
    return graphString
```

It works but is awful.  How can I make this better?

Comment: Is this a typo? `'a': {'c', 'd'}`  `a -> ['b', 'c']`

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I just changed it.  Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant your assignment to be this:

```
x = {'b': {'d'}, 'a': {'b', 'c'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 'c': {'e', 'f'}, 'e': {'d'}}
```

(The values associated with keys 'b' and 'e' are in quotes, and the value associated with key 'a' is {'b', 'c'}, not {'c', 'd'})

Then this will give the output you listed:

```
for k in sorted(x.keys()):
    print("{} -> {}".format(k, sorted(list(x[k]))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = {'b': {'d'}, 'a': {'c', 'd'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 'c': {'e', 'f'}, 'e': {'d'}}


def graph_as_str(x):
    sorted_x = sorted(x)

    for i in x:
        print i, "-->", list(x[i])
```

Hope this solves what you need and is much simpler. Enjoy!!!!

Comment: Yes, I forgot that by default, if you iterate over a dict, it iterates over the keys.  So the `.keys()` portion of my answer is unnecessary.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming d is meant to be quoted as well:

```
x = {'b': {'d'}, 'a': {'c', 'b'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 
    'c': {'e', 'f'}, 'e': {'d'}}

x_str = '\n'.join([key + ' -> ' + str(sorted(list(val))) 
                   for key, val in sorted(x.iteritems())])
print(x_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

OP did request a function, and gave a precise format:

```
x = {'b': {'d'}, 'a': {'c', 'b'}, 'd': {'g'}, 'f': {'d', 'g'}, 'c': {'e', 'f'}, 'e': {'d'}}

def graph_as_str(graph: {str:{str}}) -> str:
    return "\n".join("  {} -> {}".format(key, sorted(value)) for key, value in sorted(graph.items()))
```